# How can I prevent SSMS from re-writing my code when saving a view?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm creating a view that uses a statement with a `WHERE` clause similar to this:

```
WHERE
    (
        col1 IS NOT NULL
        OR
        col2 IS NOT NULL
    )
    AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)
```

which takes an average of 10 seconds to run.  However, when I try to save this query as a View, SQL Server (or the MS SQL Server Management Studio Client) "optimizes" the query to use this structure, instead:

```
WHERE
    (col1 IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...))
    OR
    (col2 IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...))
```

Slowing down the query to 6+ minutes.  Is there any way to disable this behavior, so that the view uses exactly the SQL Query I give it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't use the SSMS wizards.

just type your `CREATE VIEW dbo.Foo AS SELECT ...` statement into a new query window and execute it.

This will stop it rearranging the query syntax to semantically equivalent but worse performing alternatives.

Comment: And all views, stored procs, UDFs, table, etc all objects created or changed should be in script anyway so they can be put into source control like all other code.

Comment: There are a few graphical SQL tools out there that are decent and won't do stupid stuff like this

Comment: @Earlz true, but I think we all know we're talking about SSMS specifically, not all graphical tools in general.